# How do i log in to a specific gmail account in incognito mode using command line?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, google-chrome

How do i log in to a specific gmail account in incognito mode using command line?, i want to put that on startup, thats why.

Answer (score 2):

Intriguing question I got close...

```
chromium-browser https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?Email=froglegs@gmail.com&password=asecret -incognito
```

As its difficult to push the password as it expects a post with about 20+ other parameters I think this is the closest you will get.